# R - Plot sales volume on a map

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggmap

I'm trying to plot the volume of the sales on a map with ggplot2 and ggmap. 
I tried to do that with these lines, but of course the plot is not right, because the map is darker where I have the most concentration of customers (but it doesn't mean that in those places I have the higher sales volume):

```
ggmap(my.map,extent="device")+
      stat_density2d(data=sales.data,aes(x=lon,y=lat,fill=..level..,alpha=..level..),
         size=0.01,bins=20,geom="polygon")+ scale_fill_gradient(low = "green", high = "red")
              +scale_alpha(range=c(0,0.3),guide=FALSE)
```

The dataset contains 3 columns: lon, lat and sales volume. Clearly I'd like the map to get "darker" near the coordinates that have the greatest sales volume.
Is there any R function to do that?

Thanks

Comment: I think that either you can go into spatial modelling (e.g. krigging) or keep it simple and plot bubbles for every data point that are sized relatively to the sales volume. But if data is really dense at some places than the latter will give you a messy plot.

Comment: I think I've found the solution using shapefiles and spplot within the sp package. Thank you